# Is there more like OSGi?

Tags: osgi

Eclipse is based on an implementation of the [OSGi](https://www.osgi.org/) framework.

Are there more attempts like OSGi? I.e. are there more specifications that define a generic architecture of a software eco system? Are there more concepts that lay out the pattern for a complex extandable organism composed of modules that interact and communicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as far as I am aware of. Which is sad because the specifications provide a comprehensive model of software engineering that is way more useful that most software practitioners and theorists see.

Note that OSGi does not stop at the runtime. With its capability & requirements model it provides a solid base for large scale software engineering.

The only thing it is bad at are hacks and shortcuts.